# R is making wrong contingency tables for me

Tags: r, contingency

I am creating a contingency table for Fisher's Exact test from my 'covid' dataframe using the table function. The table is the following

```
table1 <- matrix(c(117,390,861,669),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(table1) <- c("No","Yes")
rownames(table1) <- c("Hospital","House")
table1 <- as.table(table1)
table1
```

The code I wrote to make the table was following:

```
table1 = table(covid$Treatment_place, covid$Cognitive_dysfunction)
table1
          No         Yes
Hospital (a)117    (b)390 
House    (c) 861   (d)669
```

However, my suspicion is that R is not counting my positive and negative cases correctly. In this case, cell b and c would be positive cases (I have manually labelled the cells for your understanding), but R is counting them as negative and therefore giving a flawed analysis. The following is the odds ratio given by R, which is possible only if R counts cell a and d as positive cases (which should be negative cases).

```
fisher.test (table1)
  
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
data: table1
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
0.1836178 0.2947950
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
0.2332679
```

Is there any way I can specify which cells are to be counted as positives ? I think if I can interchange my 'Yes' and 'No' columns it would give me a correct result too, but I don't know how.

Also, is there any way I can transfer the original column names as table labels?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: if your columns are flipped, just use 1/OR. or `fisher.test(table1[, 2:1])`. you can add names to tables: `table(row_label = ..., col_label = ...)`